# Alterando WWW no WampServer 3

Tags: wamp

Boa Tarde,

Já alterei o arquivo httpd.conf as linhas
DocumentRoot "d:/var/www"

Mas quando peço para abrir o www ainda está direcionando na anterior.
D:\wamp64\www

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como resolver isso?

Informações
Windows 10 Pro
WampServer Version 3.0.4 - 64bit

Comment: Eu tive esse problema também e depois eu descobri que é necessário trocar os mesmos valores no arquivo httpd-vhosts.conf que está localizado em \conf\extra. Abraços